# Volvo S40 Immobilizer Problem

Tags: troubleshooting, volvo

I got the following error msgs from my Volvo S40 and the car wont start.
- Immobilizer :  check manual
as I tried to start the car,  I got :
- System service required.

What does this entail and what's required on me to do?

Comment: Have you tried to start it with another (spare) key?